# Showing that the complexification of $SU(n)$ is $SL_n(\mathbb C)$

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, representation-theory, lie-groups

I'm trying to show that the complexification of $SU(n)$ is $SL_n(\mathbb C)$. I know that generally (by the Cartan decomposition which appears [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complexification_(Lie_group))) the complexification is obtained by:
$$SU(n)_\mathbb{C}=G_0\cdot P_0$$
Where -
$$G_0=SU(n)\cap U(n)=SU(n)$$
$$P_0=SU(n)\cap P(n)$$
Where $P(n)$ are the positive matrices. Moreover, by the usual polar decomposition theorem, I know that:
$$SL_n(\mathbb C)=SU(n)\cdot P_1$$
Where $P_1=P(n)\cap SL_n(\mathbb C)$. So basically, I need to show that:
$$SU(n)\cdot P_0=SU(n)\cdot P_1$$
One inclusion is obvious - $P_0\subset P_1$ and so the LHS is contained in the RHS. How can I show the other inclusion? Also, does this method seem okay?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: On the level of lie algebras, it's relatively simple to show ${\frak sl}(n,\Bbb C)$ is a direct sum ${\frak su}(n)\oplus i {\frak su}(n)$. I'm guessing complexification of a Lie *group* is more precise though?

Comment: @runway44 That's right, I'm looking for the complexification of the Lie group, not the Lie algebra.